# Awk or Sed entries in a file > than last hour

Tags: date, search, range, ksh

I'm defining my time variables via ksh script:

```
NOW="$(date +"%I:%OM")"
LASTHOUR="$(date +%I:%OM --date "last hour")"
```

my log output contains the following format:

```
019723  01/22 01:00  err  PoolEndorseServ::notify   Error while notifying in...
019722  01/22 00:00  err  PoolEndorseServ::notify   Error while notifying in...
019722  01/21 05:10  err  PoolEndorseServ::notify   Error while notifying in...
```

I want to be able to pull any records that are > than $LASTHOUR by looking at the time column.

Any assistance or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your time field is in the 24 hour format.

With `awk`:

```
awk -v LASTHOUR="$(date --date "last hour" "+%m/%d %H:%0M")" \
  '$2" "$3 > LASTHOUR' < yourfile
```

This will break if it's the first hour of January 1st, though. That can't be helped because you don't provide the year in the log.